# .net SOAP Clients generate 404 errors when attempting to use JAX-WS SOAP RPC Web Services

Tags: .net, tomcat, soap, jax-ws, http-status-code-404

In my current project I have to connect to a [JAX-WS web service](http://jax-ws.java.net/) from a **.net** client.

The **JAX-WS web service** runs on a **tomcat server**.  I'm able to test and use the Web Service with a simple **ruby** script:

```
# test_web_services.rb

require 'rubygems'
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'

def get_driver
    wsdl_url = 'http://localhost:8080/services/RPCService?WSDL'
    return SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(wsdl_url).create_rpc_driver
end

driver = get_driver
driver.createOrganization ARGV[0], "organization-name-parameter"
```

I can also connect with [**SoapUI**](http://www.soapui.org/) (a SOAP gui testing tool), but no matter how hard I try I cannot seem to hit the web service with a .net Soap Client of any kind.

Also I am unable to view the wsdl with the browser.  Almost all errors are [404s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404).   I even went so far as to try and precisely mimic the [request headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) coming from the ruby script in my .net code, but to no avail.   I also deactivated my [firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_%28computing%29), just in case.

The JAX-WS service is started from a bean when the website starts up:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter">
        <property name="baseAddress" value="http://localhost:8080/services/"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="RPCServiceEndpoint" class="com.package.RPCServiceEndpoint"/>
```

Here’s the annotations **RPCServiceEndpoint.java** uses:

```
@WebService(serviceName="RPCService")
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
@Autowired applied to constructor
@WebMethod applied to each SOAP method
```

**I’ve tried almost every SOAP client .net library since the beginning of the .net framework and I still get 404s.**

### How can I hit this JAX-WS web service with a .net SOAP client?

Note: I've tried to hit the [wsdl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) with [wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx)'s [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx), but they are just as blind to the web service as my homemade clients are.